# Scala parser combinator: Failure - eol (end of line) expected

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I want to parse a `LOLCODE` script using Scala parser combinators. Here is what I got by far:

```
  class ValuePT(val value: String) extends ExpressionPT {
    override def toString = value
  }

  def value: Parser[ValuePT] = (numericLit | stringLit) ^^ {
    case a => new ValuePT(a)
  }
  def expression: Parser[ExpressionPT] = (...| id | value) ^^ {
    case a => a
  }

  def statement: Parser[StatementPT] = (...|expression|...|loop) <~ eol ^^ {case a => a}

  def condition: Parser[LoopConditionPT] = (value <~ "YR") ~ id ~ opt(("TIL"|"WILE") ~ expression) ^^ {
    case a ~ b ~ Some(c ~ d) => new LoopConditionPT(a toString, b, Option(c -> d))
    case a ~ b ~ None => new LoopConditionPT(a toString, b, Option("None" -> new IdentPT("-1")))
  }

  def loop: Parser[LoopPT] = ("IM IN YR" ~> id ~ opt(condition) <~ eol) ~ rep(statement) <~ "IM OUTTA YR" <~ id ^^ {
    case a ~ b ~ c => new LoopPT(a, b, c)
  }
```

My test case looks like this:

```
HAI 1.2
    IM IN YR UntilLoop UPPIN YR Var TIL BOTH SAEM Var AN 3
        VISIBLE "UntilLoop " Var
    IM OUTTA YR UntilLoop

    IM IN YR WhileLoop bla YR Var 
        VISIBLE "WhileLoop " Var
    IM OUTTA YR WhileLoop

    I HAS A x ITZ 1
    I HAS A y ITZ 1
    IM IN YR NestedLoop
        IM IN YR InnerLoop
            VISIBLE "NestedLoop " x " " y
            GTFO
        IM OUTTA YR InnerLoop
        GTFO
    IM OUTTA YR NestedLoop
KTHXBYE
```

But my function doesn't work, it raises an error:

```
 [2.24] failure: eol expected

  IM IN YR UntilLoop UPPIN YR Var TIL BOTH SAEM Var AN 3

                     ^
```

I don't understand and I don't know what causes the error, is it says that I was missing `eol` before `UPPIN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is clear from the code is that `condition` is failing to match, which is fine from the parser's perspective because its `opt(condition)`. But when it fails, it is expecting an `eol` next.

It looks like you are expecting `condition` to match the rest of the line. Because you get the error at `eol`, that means that `condition` fails on the first token, because otherwise Scala would have reported the error from the branch that made further progress. Without the definition of `value`, it is impossible to tell what exactly is failing, but **a general rule for debugging `opt` parsers is to remove the `opt` when testing examples**. This way, you always get an error from the inside of `opt` rather than letting `opt` quietly match nothing.